# Migration notice on destination site is incorrect

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

When migrating a question to another site, the following notice is added:

> #### migrated from [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) 2 mins ago
>
> This question came from our site for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development.

This appears to be an artifact from the early beta: the site isn't for [expert programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/removing-expert-from-the-site-description) or [discussions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) anymore.

Can this be changed to match the [current FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) opening line?

> #### migrated from [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) 2 mins ago
>
> This question came from our site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed, may take a while to filter through the caches