# Are answers to homework questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can Programmers.SE be used to assist students with class assignments?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/how-can-programmers-se-be-used-to-assist-students-with-class-assignments)

The question [How to solve this problem without the use of if-else statements?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151312/how-to-solve-this-problem-without-the-use-of-if-else-statements)
was recently asked. And somebody [answered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151312/how-to-solve-this-problem-without-the-use-of-if-else-statements/151328#151328) with the full solution to their problem, code and all.

I don't think they kind of behavior should be allowed as it does not benefit the student at all. It almost seems like people who do that are doing it for the reputation. And not for the good of the student, since it does no good for the student to be handed the answer.

But what is the official consensus on this? Am I totally in the wrong here?

Comment: Also see  [Is it OK to ask P.SE to do your job?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/is-it-ok-to-ask-p-se-to-do-your-job), [Addendum to off topic themes in the FAQ](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/addendum-to-off-topic-themes-in-the-faq), and [Removing the \[homework\] tag](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/removing-the-homework-tag)

Comment: @MarkTrapp Thanks, put in my vote to close it. =P